# MVC/LINQ - nested where request who doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I encounter a problem with a nested Where clauses request in a Razor view (Asp.net MVC  with EF 6) :

Here is my request (Model is an IEnumarable from controller, it has correct values) :

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Where(p => (p.user.SellGoods.Where(g => g.IsBuy == false)) != null))
```

My Good model is :

```
    [Key]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String UrlImage { get; set; }

    [MinLength(10), MaxLength(500)]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public float Price { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> EndOfAuction { get; set; }

    public virtual EnumStrategy Strategy { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User user { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsBuy { get; set; }

    public int CurrentAuctionWinner { get; set; }
```

And my User model :

```
    [EmailAddress]
    public String Mail { get; set; }

    [Column("SellGoods")]
    public virtual ICollection<Good> SellGoods { get; set; }

    [Column("BuyGoods")]
    public virtual ICollection<Good> BuyGoods { get; set; }

    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual Address BillingAdress { get; set; }

    [Range(0.00d, 10.00d)]
    public double Rate { get; set; }
```

With my current request, I got all the Good sell by one member like the `(g => g.IsBuy == false)` doesn't work..

Does someone knows what is wrong?

Great thanks !

Comment: `Where()` would always return `IEnumerable<Good>` hence would always be non-null. Perhaps you meant `Model.Where(p => p.user.SellGoods.Any(g => g.IsBuy)` (All the goods which their associated user has at least one `Good` in its `SellGoods` collection that is not marked as `IsBuy`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the condition is not satisfied in a `Where()` LINQ extension method an empty `IEnumerable` is returned. So your condition is never met. Use the `Any()` instead of `Where() != null`, like so:

```
@foeach (var item in Model.Where(p => p.user.SellGoods.Any(g => !g.IsBuy)))
```